# Deleting Single Element From Same Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For the following code:

```
    document.getElementById('text_one').onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13') {
            text = document.getElementById('text_one').value;
            if (text == "" || text === null || text.length > 50) {
                $('#error_msg').show('slow');
                document.getElementById('text_one').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('text_one').value = "";
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#list').append('<li>' + text + '</li><br />');
                document.getElementById('text_one').value = "";
            }
        }
    };
```

How would one go about making a function that deletes the element which was clicked? I was thinking that you could somehow create a specific number that increases every time the function is run and use that number to create custom ID's but I'm not sure how to do that.
 
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dd5L/ (The CSS is messed up for some reason)

Comment: A tip, you don't need all that event stuff, jQuery normalizes `e.which`. Also note that this works `keyCode == '13'` because you're using loose comparison, but key codes are numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using jQuery it's very simple (in pure JS also just 2 more lines of code):

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2dd5L/1/